# Loop in Jade nodejs

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to create pagination in `jade` using `nodejs`

But there is problem in creating links, my code is:

```
    ul#pagination
-       for (var i = 0; i < #{count}; i++){
            li
                a(href='/home/i')= i
-       }
```

I also tried `a(href='/home/#{i}') #{i}` and `a(href='/home/'+i)= i` but not works

`#{count}` gives me the `total number of pages`,but the `loop` is `not working` properly.
**Why?**

Comment: 1. in what way is the loop not working? 2. are you sure count has the correct value? 3. it should be `count` not `#{count}`

Comment: Yes I tried `p #{count}` which gives `<p>3 </p>` , also I tried `i < 3;` in `for loop` but it not works.

Comment: What does not work? What is wrong?

Comment: In my `HTML` it does not creates `li a`, it gives only `<ul id="pagination"></ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the indentation and it works for me:

```
ul#pagination
    - for (var i=1; i<=count; i++)
        li
            a(href='/home/'+i)= i
```

If not `work` then create a new `jade file` and then `include` it by **include newfile** , and test, if it works then copy all contents of `new file` in your `original file`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with some syntax in the Jade template, but you could also consider creating the link array in your node script, exposing it to the template and using a regular [each loop](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a9).

Comment: There is no `array`, here is the `total number` I used for `pagination`.

Comment: No, but you can create the array in your node script.